# Building QGIS with Visual Studio 2015 on windows x64?

Tags: qgis

I tried to follow the guide at [github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/INSTALL), hence I encounter problem after problem (Now I have problems with: `MSBuild.exe  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:`, earlier I couldn't find any c++ paths etc.) I assume that I have done some mistake and missed something running the installation.

I'm curious if there is anyone that recently have build QGIS on Windows(10) with Visual Studio(2015) and can give some advise what to change in the .bat file, where I can set the path to bison and flex in cmake, what and where I shall use the Ninja.exe file that I downloaded according the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to compile it with the same env you are using

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 15

I'm able to start the build and I reach more or less the 98% than it fails generating some errors.
Seems it is not able to properly read spatialindex.h file

**What I've done**

- Install Cmake
- Downloading cygwin and install bison, flex, git
- Downloading OsGeoW 64bit version and install qgis-rel-deps
- Create the bat file named as you wish as below:

  `@echo off
  set OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64
  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat"
  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat"
  call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat"
  set O4W_ROOT=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%
  set LIB_DIR=%O4W_ROOT%
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 10.0.16299.0
  path %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin
  path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\cygwin\bin;
  @set GRASS_PREFIX=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0
  @set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include;
  @set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;
  set LIB=%LIB%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\lib;
  set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\include;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\include;
  @cmd`

  - Download git source
  - Create a new folder named "Build" into Qgis source dir
  - Open a prompt and navigate to "Build" folder
  - Run 
    `Batchfile
    cmake-gui ..`
  - Configure it with all required path. Please note that in my case I need to specify bison and flex path because it is not able to retrieve it. The same for the SpatialIndex library
  - Once configuration is completed without errors click on "Generate" specifying your version
  - Then Open the project and build the "ALL_BUILD" solution

Unfortunately in my case qgis_core fails due to a problem with spatialindex.h file (not able to locate it)

Hoping this can help you